# Max Upload file size direcline.botframework.com

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

Max Upload file size direcline.botframework.com

I use the BotFramework-WebChat (webview) and the photo is superior at 10Mo.

[image]

My web.config is : `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />`

But has not effect. How to up the value for https://directline.botframework.com I have an error 500 and my bot has no responses

Conversation : G78mKAnIZVR8vcJvrStav4

Response :

`{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Per Stack Overflow user [@nilsw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5199616/nilsw) email:

> The Direct Line API that backs the WebChat control has a 4mb limit as of 2017-12-27 - You can read more in the discussion here:
>
> https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/789

That's the reason you are getting error in webchat